# Tab size in R Editor

Tags: r

I am wondering if it is possible to define a tab size in R Editor? I know I can use some other text editor, but I would prefer R Editor, as it has built-in support for executing line or selection.

Comment: What platform is this?  There are plenty of other editors that have R support...

Comment: I'm a bit dense today. What's an "R editor"?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If with an R-editor you mean the script thingy in RGUI then no, since this is a very plain text editor.

You might want to look at other text editors. Tinn-R (http://www.sciviews.org/Tinn-R/) has built in support for line/selection execution (I think, haven't used it in a while), and notepad++ (http://notepad-plus-plus.org/) can do this with help of NppToR (http://sourceforge.net/projects/npptor/).

I am not sure about Tin-R, but in notepad++ you can change tab size by going to setting -> preferences, language menu/tab settings tab, and then on the right side you can change settings (including size) of tabs.

Comment: If that be the case, my vote's with Eclipse and StatET plugin that transforms Eclipse into one mean, lean developing environment machine.

Comment: And/or if you have high scores on the "Geekness" scale, use Emacs + ESS, and do whatever you feel like doin'. =)